# Removing the last object in a node in a manual linked list implementation

Tags: java, linked-list

My current implementation of the removal operation of linked lists only works when the Node to be removed is not at the end of the list. I need the previous Node to now point to null, instead of pointing to the last Node, in order for it to be deleted. Instead of throwing a NullPointerException, the remove operation for the last Node just keeps the list as is. How would I change the `else if` condition to reflect this?

```
public Book remove(Book bookToRemove){

    Node current = head; //each Node stores a Book

    if(isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No books to remove!");
    }
    
    //what happens if the next next one is null?
    while(current.getNext() != null && !isEmpty()){
        if(current.getNext().getBook().equals(bookToRemove)){
            Node temp = current.getNext();
            current.setNext(temp.getNext());
            return bookToRemove;
        }

        
        else if(current.getNext() == null){ //
            //if the next node is null, it cannot be removed, or the previous node will have nothing to point to
            current.setNext(null);
            return bookToRemove;
        }

        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return bookToRemove;
}
```

Comment: You should to the `else` case first, checking if `current.getNext() == null`. That avoids the NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the initial suggestion, just check the head node first and if that is the one to be removed, make the change to the `head` and exit the function. The rest of the flow will take care of removing at any other location in the list.

```
public Book remove(Book bookToRemove)
{
    Node current = head; //each Node stores a Book

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("No books to remove!");
        return bookToRemove;   //no need to continue
    }

    if(current.getBook().equals(bookToRemove))
    {
      //found in head itself, make new head and exit
      head = current.getNext();
      return bookToRemove;
    }
    while(current.getNext() != null && !isEmpty())
    {
        if(current.getNext().getBook().equals(bookToRemove))
        {
            Node temp = current.getNext();
            current.setNext(temp.getNext());
            return bookToRemove;
        }        
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return bookToRemove;
}
```

Comment: I understand this logic where the previous Node needs the next one to be set to null to remove the current Node, however after testing this code, the list remains the same without removing the given Node

Comment: Fill your list with few book objects and step through the removing function, then you could find where it goes wrong. The place where this function is being called must also be checked for correctness.

Comment: The above snippet doesn't check the first node, that needs to be done.

Comment: I have modified the code, just check the head node first, and if it is not the one to remove, then check rest of the list. No need for the `prev` node. Use this updated function and remove a node, then print the list and check if your node is removed, it should work.